# "User defined type not defined" when trying to define a new "process"

Tags: vb.net, command-line, outputstream

I am trying to redirect command line output to a list box in a vba macro, and I've found some code that I think might point me in the right direction, but I keep on getting the same error. When I use this code

```
Function ReadCmdOutput(ByVal applicationName As String,
Optional ByVal applicationArgs As String = "", Optional ByVal
workingDirectory As String = "", Optional ByVal showWindow As Boolean
= False) As String

Try
   Dim processObj As New Process

   processObj.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
   processObj.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
   processObj.StartInfo.FileName = applicationName
   processObj.StartInfo.Arguments = applicationArgs
   processObj.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory

   If showWindow = True Then
      processObj.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
   Else
      processObj.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
   End If

   processObj.Start()
   processObj.WaitForExit()

   Return processObj.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
   Catch ex As Exception
   Return ""
End Try

End Function
```

It gives me the error in the title and highlights the first declaration line.

Question: What does it take to define a new "process".

Bonus points: Helping me with command line output redirect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be VBA since there is no Try/Catch in VBA or `return` statements. This looks like VB.NET. Either way, the compiler is telling you that there is currently no reference to any dll that contains the process object.

If this is VB.NET, you need to add `Imports System.Diagnostics`

Comment: That would be Imports, not Include